# Which atomic model is most associated with shells?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

Would the Bohr model be enough to explain electron shells? Especially the valence and conduction shells.

Comment: Do you mean valence and conduction *bands* (in solids)?

Comment: Yes, I assume that the isolated version of the valence band is the valence shell , so wouldn't the isolated version of the conduction band be conduction shell? Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean the concept of shells with distinct high probability bands in general or the proper concept of probability clouds. Or are you more interested in introducing energy levels?

Comment: The concept of shells with distinct high probability bands in general.

Comment: Yes, introducing energy levels specifically.

Comment: The link between atomic energy levels and band structure of solids is perhaps more tenuous than you think.

Comment: "As the atoms approach one another to form the solid, the wave functions of their electrons start to overlap. The interactions between the electrons cause the discrete energy levels of each of the isolated to split into a huge a number of energy levels forming a band of levels". Source: https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=eefKBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA178&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

No, the model would / does not explain shells. It cannot deal with the concept of an upper limit on electron occupancy for each shell and it cannot explain the  splitting of the spectral lines observed in the presence of external  magnetic fields. The structure and behaviour of the atom would still be a mystery under the Bohr model.